# PHP xml retain tags in childNode

Tags: php, xml

I fetched this string on to the database:

`$str = "<ol><li><span style=&quot;color:rgb(255,153,0);&quot;><b style=&quot;color:rgb(255,153,0);&quot;>Maximum</b></span> authority</li><li>Innovative response</li><li>Freedom<br></li></ol>";`

I wanted to split the string into an array, having the values inside `<li>` to be the value and coming up with something like this:

```
[0] => <span style=&quot;color:rgb(255,153,0);&quot;><b style=&quot;color:rgb(255,153,0);&quot;>Maximum</b></span> authority
[1] => Innovative response
[2] => Freedom<br>
```

However, I only come up with this solution:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($str);
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li)
  $final_list[] = $li->nodeValue;

// Results
[0] => Maximum authority
[1] => Innovative response
[2] => Freedom
```

It strips the HTML tags inside `<li>` which is not my expected result. Any ideas to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($str);
$final_list = array();
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
    $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument();
    $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($li, true));
    $h = trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML());
    $final_list[] = substr($h, strpos($h,'>')+1, -(strlen($li->nodeName)+3));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It does work, however it adds quotes and doing something like this `<span style='"color:rgb(255,153,0);"'><b style='"color:rgb(255,153,0);"'>` instead of `<span style="&quot;color:rgb(255,153,0);&quot;"><b style="&quot;color:rgb(255,153,0);&quot;">`

Comment: Oh, I checked the code in CLI and it works fine. One possible solution is to remove the extra ' character with strreplace or preg_replace.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I tweaked your answer a little then do some adjustments on some of my scripts, added a `ENT_NOQUOTES` on `htmlentities()`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php u need to use saveXML to retain HTML

```
$final_list[] = htmlentities($xml->saveXML($li), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: Almost there, I don't need the <li> to be included.